# parted + usage help not described the resizepart

Tags: redhat, lvm, partition, fdisk, parted

we need to use parted command as example on rhel server 7.2 version

```
parted -s /dev/sda resizepart 2
```

but from parted help we not find the option `resizepart`

example:

```
parted -s /dev/sda resizepart 2
Usage: parted [OPTION]... [DEVICE [COMMAND [PARAMETERS]...]...]
Apply COMMANDs with PARAMETERS to DEVICE.  If no COMMAND(s) are given, run in
interactive mode.

OPTIONs:
  -h, --help                      displays this help message
  -l, --list                      lists partition layout on all block devices
  -m, --machine                   displays machine parseable output
  -s, --script                    never prompts for user intervention
  -v, --version                   displays the version
  -a, --align=[none|cyl|min|opt]  alignment for new partitions

COMMANDs:
  align-check TYPE N                        check partition N for TYPE(min|opt) alignment
  help [COMMAND]                           print general help, or help on COMMAND
  mklabel,mktable LABEL-TYPE               create a new disklabel (partition table)
  mkpart PART-TYPE [FS-TYPE] START END     make a partition
  name NUMBER NAME                         name partition NUMBER as NAME
  print [devices|free|list,all|NUMBER]     display the partition table, available devices, free space, all found partitions, or a particular partition
  quit                                     exit program
  rescue START END                         rescue a lost partition near START and END
  rm NUMBER                                delete partition NUMBER
  select DEVICE                            choose the device to edit
  disk_set FLAG STATE                      change the FLAG on selected device
  disk_toggle [FLAG]                       toggle the state of FLAG on selected device
  set NUMBER FLAG STATE                    change the FLAG on partition NUMBER
  toggle [NUMBER [FLAG]]                   toggle the state of FLAG on partition NUMBER
  unit UNIT                                set the default unit to UNIT
  version                                  display the version number and copyright information of GNU Parted
```

and our perted version is'

```
parted --version
parted (GNU parted) 3.1
Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by <http://git.debian.org/?p=parted/parted.git;a=blob_plain;f=AUTHORS>.
```

is it possible or mistake from usage help?

or really `resizepart` not supported ?

reference - https://access.redhat.com/sites/default/files/attachments/parted_0.pdf

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1423357

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is kind if weird but to get help on parted commands, device parameter is must.

```
parted [device] help [command]
```

Command can be resizepart, mkpart, print etc. (You can get the list of all commands using parted -h)

e.g. `parted /dev/sda help resizepart`

```
# parted /dev/sda help resizepart
  resizepart NUMBER END                    resize partition NUMBER

    NUMBER is the partition number used by Linux.  On MS-DOS disk labels, the primary partitions number from 1 to 4, logical partitions from 5 onwards.
        END is disk location, such as 4GB or 10%.  Negative value counts from the end of the disk.  For example, -1s specifies exactly the last sector.
```